# Environment definition separates matching braces

Tags: environments

Suppose I want to define an environment which is essentially a modification of an existing one. I tried something like that:

```
\newenvironment{newenv}{%
  \formatcommand{\begin{oldenv}%
}{%
  \end{oldenv}}%
}
```

I would expect

```
\begin{newenv}Foo\end{newenv}
```

to result in the same output as

```
\formatcommand{\begin{oldenv}Foo\end{oldenv}}
```

But whenever I use `\begin{newenv}`, `pdflatex` says

```
Missing } inserted
```

and skrews up everything afterwards, of course. Without `\formatcommand` everything is fine, so apparently the orphan `{` form `\formatcommand` is the culprit.

My guess is that `pdflatex` tries to treat stuff inside environment definition parts as something syntactically correct---which what I do clearly is not---instead of "just" to replace text and parse afterwards.

Is there a way to get around this, i.e. have a command span from a new environments beginning to end?

**Use case:**

```
\newenvironment{card}{%
  \resizebox{55mm}{85mm}{\begin{tabular*}{55mm}{| p{50.5mm} |}%
  \hline%
}{%
  \hline\end{tabular*}}%
}
```

If I put the *same* `resizebox` around the usage site of `card`, it compiles and resizes (even though not the way I intended, but that's for another day).

Comment: Not sure what you are tying to do here. Why are you passing the `\begin{oldenv}` to `\formatcommand`?

Comment: It mostly depends on what `\formatcommand` is supposed to do and on what `oldenv` is. A "real world" example is needed.

Comment: I would have thought that this issue relates to general properties of (La)TeX, but there you go.

Comment: @PeterGrill I want to have `\formatcommand` applied to the whole environment `oldenv`. As I repeat `card` often in the application and need the same resize, I figured an environment def would be the place to put it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For applying some macro/command to the body of an environment, you may want to extract the entire body into a macro itself. This can be done (to whatever limited extent) using the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\NewEnviron{itquote}{%
  \itshape% Set shape to italics
  \begin{quote}
    \BODY% regular \BODY of itquote environment
  \end{quote}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}% Original quote environment
  Here is a very simple quote
\end{quote}
\begin{itquote}% New itquote environment
  Here is a very simple quote
\end{itquote}
\end{document}
​
```

​[image]

In the above (admittedly elementary) example, `itquote` italicizes its contents (stored in the macro `\BODY`). For some, it provides a more intuitive way of working with environments within environments.

Additionally, it is always good to view the package documentation (and sometimes even the package source `.sty`). For example, although `minipage` is an environment and is typically used in the context of `\begin{minipage}{<width>} ... \end{minipage}` it can also be used in a "macro pair form" using `\minipage{<width} ... \endminipage`. Again, for some, this allows for a more intuitive way of splitting environment begin/end's over a new environment definition.

Comment: That works wonderfully, thanks! Good hint regarding macro pairs, too, even though I don't see myself digging is `sty` files.

Answer (score 6):

You can't leave unbalanced braces in a definition. That's forbidden by TeX's syntax rules.

There is a workaround:

```
\newsavebox{\cardbox}
\newenvironment{card}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\cardbox}
   \begin{tabular*}{55mm}{| p{50.5mm} |}
   \hline
  }
  {\hline
   \end{tabular}
   \end{lrbox}%
   \resizebox{55mm}{85mm}{\usebox{\cardbox}}%
  }
```

The contents of the environment is saved in the `\cardbox` bin which is later processed.

See Werner's answer for another method which is particularly useful in other situations.

Comment: I don't understand what happens here, and it seems a lot of boilerplate compared to `environ`. Does your solution have technical advantages?

Comment: For example, environments defined with **environ** can't go in the argument of commands, nor in the definition of other environments. The `lrbox` way uses only kernel methods (except `\resizebox`, of course).

Comment: I see. In my case, the environment in queston is going to be top-level so I'll stick with `environ`, but I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of defining a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{MyQuote}{%
    \begin{quote}%
    % Add customization that goes after the start of the environment here
}{%
    % Add customization that goes before the end of the environment here
    \end{quote}%
}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{MyQuote}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{MyQuote}
\end{document}
```

I suspect that you are trying to use some macro of the form `\macro{}` and attempting to add the `\macro{` at the beginning and `}` at the end environment. Don't think this is allowed with the standard `\newenvironment`.  You could use [the `environ` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/environ), with which provides access to the body of the environment via `\BODY`.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{MyQuote}{%
  \quote%
  \textcolor{red}{\BODY}%
}{%
  \endquote%
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{MyQuote}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{MyQuote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer does not relate to the question. I tried to clarify that the general way of defining new environments is not the issue (or so I think) but specifically how to have a command span from before its begin to after its end.

Comment: See updated regarding the `environ` package.

Answer (score 0):

What should `\formatcommand` do?

Your definition has no balanced braces, I hope the following sequence shows, what happens:

```
\newenvironment{newenv}{%Open parameter 2 of \newenvironment
  \formatcommand{\begin{oldenv}%
}%this closes formatcommand
{%you open a group
  \end{oldenv}
}%The group is closed%
}%you close parameter 2 of \newenvironment
%%Now you should get the 3rd parameter of \newenvironment
```

Comment: This clearly is what happens and I stated as much in the question. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

*Update.* I'll leave it here as a *non-answer*, see comments below.

---

It looks like `\bgroup` and `\egroup` can help.  I am not an expert and not sure if this is the right way to do, but the following works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{oldenv}{*}{*}
\newenvironment{newenv}{\textit\bgroup\begin{oldenv}}{\end{oldenv}\egroup}
\begin{document}
  \begin{newenv}
    Test
  \end{newenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just by chance. You're passing `\bgroup` as the argument to `\textit` and the business *seems* to work, but really by chance.

Comment: @egreg, is there no way to make something like this with `\begingroup` or `\bgroup`?

Comment: Not really. The syntax rules of TeX are that an (undelimited) argument is either the next token or, if the next token is `{` (not `\bgroup`), the whole token list up to the matching `}`, which TeX absorbs immediately without interpreting anything.