# Curve rubric entry with hanging indentation

Tags: indentation, curve-class

I was trying to get a hanging indentation, so an indentation from second line. There are multiple answers for how to achieve this in general texts or lists. But I could not transfer them to the `curve` package in a `rubric` environment.

MWE:

```
% doc.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{curve}

\begin{document}
\makerubric{history}
\end{document}

% history.tex
\begin{rubric}{History}
\entry*[2018]%
    \textbf{That's now}.
\entry*[2016 -- \rlap{$\:\:\dots$}\phantom{2016}]
    \textbf{Last two years}. Great times.
\entry*[2012 -- 2016]%
    \textbf{A few years before}. If there is a long entry like this one
    I would like to have a hanging indentation (i.\,e. indentation from second line).
\end{rubric}
```

[image: MWE looks like this]

I was trying to look into `curve.cls`, but this is way beyond my understanding of tex. I think it has to do with the `\entry` command from there:

```
\newcommand\@entry[2][]{%
  \gdef\@nextentry{}\@key{#1}%
  \egroup% end of \noalign opened in \entry.
  \@@key&\@prefix&#2\\\par}

\newcommand\@sentry[1][]{%
  \gdef\@nextentry{\\\par}\@key{#1}%
  \egroup% end of \noalign opened in \entry.
  \@@key&\@prefix&}

\newcommand\entry{%
  \@nextentry
  \noalign\bgroup\gdef\@beforespace{\subrubricbeforespace}%
  \@ifstar{\@sentry}{\@entry}}
```

It looks like there is just one paragraph with the bullet point on the left. I tried the `hanging` package, the built-in commands (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254054/), but I'm a bit lost now.

Comment: @carlisle - I seem to be having a problem loading ltxtable.sty. The manual is still there, but neither MikTeX nor the package manager can find it.  BTW, one can probably fix the above using \parbox{\linewidth}{\hangindent=.5in ...}

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for this easy idea - works! :D

Comment: The `\parbox` has a smaller spacing to the next entry though...

Comment: @JohnKormylo Alright, I have a fully working solution now, using a parbox, redefining `\@entry[2][]`. Do you want to post an answer, or would it be ok if I answer my working solution with corrected spaces now?

Comment: I've lost my working file and never got curve to run.  Answering you own question if fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to John Kormylo (see comments above) I found the solution below for my problem. I had to use the `\entry{}` command rather than `\entry*` to make it work.

There was an issue with too small spaces after the `parbox`, corrected by the `\strut` usage, taken from here: [Vertical space after minipage (EDIT : in an environment)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349178/vertical-space-after-minipage-edit-in-an-environment).

I added a second long line to show the corrected spacing. Note the `[t]` in `\parbox[t]`. This is neccessary to have the bullet point on the first line rather than the center of the parbox. In the questionable case of having more than one paragraph in the parbox, there are curly brackets after `\hangindent`. This will make it work for all paragraphs instead of just the first one.

```
% doc.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{curve}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@entry[2][]{%
    \gdef\@nextentry{}\@key{#1}%
    \egroup% end of \noalign opened in \entry.
    \@@key&\@prefix&\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\hangindent=2em {\strut#2\strut}}\\\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makerubric{history}
\end{document}

% history.tex
\begin{rubric}{History}
\entry*[2018]%
    \textbf{That's now}.
\entry*[2016 -- \rlap{$\:\:\dots$}\phantom{2016}]
    \textbf{Last two years}. Great times.
\entry[2012 -- 2016]%
    {\textbf{A few years before}. If there is a long entry like this one
    I would like to have a hanging indentation (i.\,e. indentation from second line).}
\entry[2010]%
    {If there is a long entry like this one
    I would like to have a hanging indentation (i.\,e. indentation from second line).}
\end{rubric}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: There seems to be an error with the current texlive version in arch linux (`texlive-core-2018.47471-1-any.pkg.tar.xz`). It moves the first entry up, very close to the rubric title and if it is just one line, the second line will still have the same position as without moving the first line, so there's a gap between first and second line.